# Android markets submit process

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to publish my apps on a different "alternative" android markets, but this process doesn't look easy, because every market has its own restrictions and requirements like icon file size, screenshots size, etc.
what markets supports getting all the app information from android market? I found only one yet. it is mall.soc.io
they don't provide much download traffic, so I'd love to deal with markets that can automatically get description, icon and screenshots. what are my options, if any?

Comment: A downvote without a comment isn't very helpful to OP or to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We publish on both Android Market and Amazon Appstore. We just bite the bullet and prepare graphics and descriptive text separately for each one. We also generate separate .apk files, since we use the licensing library for Android Market and Amazon DRM for Amazon Appstore. (We put 90% of our app in a library project in Eclipse and the market-dependent stuff in separate application projects, linked to the library project.)

Conforming to the requirements of each market separately has its advantages in terms of presentation in the market. It's always good to weigh the relative benefits of ease of development versus the user experience. This applies to all phases of the project—from concept development through to marketing. Our view is that a good market presentation is worth the investment of labor to prepare good marketing assets.

I was not aware of mail.soc.io. When I went there, I got a warning that the site cert isn't from a trusted authority. (It seems to be a self-signed cert.) I wonder how much value there would be in publishing your app there, even if it does involve very little work on your part.

Comment: I agree on all that. My point publishing the apps to the mail.soc.io market is: it does not take any changes made to the project, or even additional time to submit apps there. from the other side, it still generates some downloads which is a plus distributing free apps.

Answer (score 0):

I had my apps submitted at Socio Mall as well. The metadata import from Android market went smooth. But i didn't find other third party stores with this features, sorry.